# Unit tests for Query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

How does one go about testing queries in SQLAlchemy? For example suppose we have this `models.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import (
        Column,
        Integer,
        String,
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Panel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Panels'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    platform = Column(String, nullable=False)
    region = Column(String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, category, platform, region):
        self.category = category
        self.platform = platform
        self.region = region


    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            "<Panel('{self.category}', '{self.platform}', "
            "'{self.region}')>".format(self=self)
        )
```

and this `tests.py`

```
import unittest

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from models import Base, Panel


class TestQuery(unittest.TestCase):

    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    def setUp(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        self.session.add(Panel(1, 'ion torrent', 'start'))
        self.session.commit()

    def tearDown(self):
        Base.metadata.drop_all(self.engine)

    def test_query_panel(self):
        expected = [Panel(1, 'ion torrent', 'start')]
        result = self.session.query(Panel).all()
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)
```

When we try running the test, it fails, even though the two Panels look identical.

```
$ nosetests
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_query_panel (tests.TestQuery)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/clasher/tmp/tests.py", line 31, in test_query_panel
    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [<Panel('1', 'ion torrent', 's... != [<Panel('1', 'ion torrent', 's...

First differing element 0:
<Panel('1', 'ion torrent', 'start')>
<Panel('1', 'ion torrent', 'start')>

  [<Panel('1', 'ion torrent', 'start')>, <Panel('2', 'ion torrent', 'end')>]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.063s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

One solution I've found is to make a query for every single instance I expect to find in the query:

```
class TestQuery(unittest.TestCase):

    ...

    def test_query_panel(self):
        expected = [
            (1, 'ion torrent', 'start'),
            (2, 'ion torrent', 'end')
        ]
        successful = True
        # Check to make sure every expected item is in the query
        try:
            for category, platform, region in expected:
                self.session.query(Panel).filter_by(
                        category=category, platform=platform,
                        region=region).one()
        except (NoResultFound, MultipleResultsFound):
            successful = False
        self.assertTrue(successful)
        # Check to make sure no unexpected items are in the query
        self.assertEqual(self.session.query(Panel).count(),
                         len(expected))
```

This strikes me as pretty ugly, though, and I'm not even getting to the point where I have a complex filtered query that I'm trying to test. Is there a more elegant solution, or do I always have to manually make a bunch of individual queries?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

your original test is on the right track, you just have to do one of two things: either make sure that two `Panel` objects of the same primary key identity compare as `True`:

```
import unittest

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from database.models import Base

class Panel(Base):
    # ...

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Panel) and other.id == self.id
```

or you can organize your test such that you make sure you're checking against the same `Panel` instance (because here we take advantage of the [identity map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html)):

```
class TestQuery(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
        self.session = Session(self.engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        self.panel = Panel(1, 'ion torrent', 'start')
        self.session.add(self.panel)
        self.session.commit()

    def tearDown(self):
        Base.metadata.drop_all(self.engine)

    def test_query_panel(self):
        expected = [self.panel]
        result = self.session.query(Panel).all()
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)
```

as far as the engine/session setup/teardown, I'd go for a pattern where you use a single engine for all tests, and assuming your schema is fixed, a single schema for all tests, then you make sure the data you work with is performed within a transaction that can be rolled back.   The `Session` can be made to work this way, such that calling `commit()` doesn't actually commit the "real" transaction, by wrapping the whole test within an explicit `Transaction`.  The example at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites illustrates this usage.    Having a ":memory:" engine on every test fixture will take up a lot of memory and not really scale out to other databases besides SQLite.

Comment: The key idea here is that you need to instantiate all objects during setup, hold on to them by assigning them as attributes to `self`, and retrieve them later, not by querying the database again, but through those `self` attributes. Also, implementing `__eq__` was unnecessary; it seems that SQLAlchemy will return the exact same instance of a model (i.e., `created_model_instance is instance_from_query` returns `True`). Lastly, it would help to revise the answer to use the transaction-rollback pattern, even though it can be deduced from reading the SQLAlchemy documentation at the provided link.

Comment: Is the answer by @zzzeek radically different in 2022 with the release of SQLAlchemy 2.0?